# Why is a lieutenant general higher than a major general?

Tags: meaning

**Since in the military ranks, lieutenant is lower than a major.   Why is it that in the rankings of generals......major general is lower than a lieutenant general?**

Comment: This is waaaaay off-topic.

Comment: Off-topic, but here's a link that explains it: http://www.xenograg.com/364/excerpts/origin-of-rank-and-grades-of-general

Comment: Could we "migrate" this question to say, the history site?

Comment: Since it based on "Lieutenant" originally meaning "assistant" it is on topic for ELU - unless somebody wanted to claim it was French-LU

Answer (score 1):

Because it comes from `Sergeant Major General` and a `Sergeant Major` is, of course, lower than a `Lieutenant`.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has the answer:

> In French history, “lieutenant du roi” was a title born by the officer sent with military powers to represent the king in certain provinces. A lieutenant du roi was sometimes known as a lieutenant general to distinguish him from lieutenants subordinate to mere captains. The sergeant acting as staff officer to the captain general was known as the sergeant-major general. This was eventually shortened to major general, while captain general was shortened to simply general. This is the reason a major outranks a lieutenant, but a lieutenant general outranks a major general.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_rank